# how to convert a text file into csv using python

Tags: python, csv, text

I have a requirement where in I need to convert my text files into csv and am using python for doing it. My text file looks like this ,

```
1. Which of the following structure are made of several layer's of cells :-
(A) Ciliated epithelium (B) Stratified epithelium
(C) Cuboidal epithelium (D) Columnar epithelium
2. Which simple epithelium tissue cells are square in vertical sections and Polygonal in horizontal section
(A) Columnar epithelium (B) Squamous epithelium
(C) Cuboidal epithelium (D) Ciliated epithelium
```

I want a CSV as follows:

```
1, "Which of the following structure are made of several layer's of cells :-", "Ciliated epithelium", "Stratified epithelium", "Cuboidal epithelium", "Columnar epithelium"
2, "Which simple epithelium tissue cells are square in vertical sections and Polygonal in horizontal section", "Columnar epithelium", "Squamous epithelium", "Cuboidal epithelium", "Ciliated epithelium"
```

I have tried multiple ways but unable to get it. Any thoughts to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the last way you tried? It would be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step-by-step example based on your example input:

```
#!python3
import csv

# Open the original file as reading text (the default.
# Open the output file per csv documentation for csv.writer use.
with open('original.txt') as fin,open('out.csv','w',newline='') as fout:
    # Read the lines stripping leading and trailing whitespace.
    lines = [line.strip() for line in fin]
    # Set up the csv writer to quote the text fields.
    w = csv.writer(fout,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    # Make sure the input file has multiples of three lines.     
    if len(lines) % 3 != 0:
        raise RuntimeError('expected multiples of 3 lines')
    # Index through the lines 3-at-a-time.
    for i in range(0,len(lines),3):
        # Break apart lines and assign to columns.
        # Make sure col1 is a numeric field so it won't get quoted.
        tmp,col2 = lines[i].split('. ')
        col1 = int(tmp)
        col3,col4 = lines[i+1][4:].split(' (B) ')
        col5,col6 = lines[i+2][4:].split(' (D) ')
        w.writerow([col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6])
```

Output:

```
1,"Which of the following structure are made of several layer's of cells :-","Ciliated epithelium","Stratified epithelium","Cuboidal epithelium","Columnar epithelium"
2,"Which simple epithelium tissue cells are square in vertical sections and Polygonal in horizontal section","Columnar epithelium","Squamous epithelium","Cuboidal epithelium","Ciliated epithelium"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code !

I am also attach the output of the csv file.

```
import csv

with open('log.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('log.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

[image]

Comment: getting the below error...>>> with open('C:\Animal1.txt', 'r') as in_file:
...     stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
...     lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
...     with open('C:\Users\chinn\Desktop\log.csv', 'w') as out_file:
...         writer = csv.writer(out_file)
...         writer.writerows(lines)
... out_file.close()
  File "<stdin>", line 7
    out_file.close()
           ^

Comment: you have specify the file path with double \\ . Now replace this 'C:\Animal1.txt' with 'C:\\Animal1.txt' and 'C:\Users\chinn\Desktop\log.csv' with 'C:\\Users\\chinn\\Desktop\\log.csv'

Comment: mate, its not converting into CSV.

Comment: >>> import csv
>>> with open('C:\\Animal1.txt', 'r') as in_file:
...     stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
...     lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
...     with open('C:\\Users\chinn\Desktop\log.csv', 'w') as out_file:
...         writer = csv.writer(out_file)
...         writer.writerows(lines)